# Cannot cast from source type to destination type

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am new to C# so I was doing some tutorials.
I get this error when I try to run a tutorial Android project from Xamarin Studio:

> A System.InvalidCastException was thrown. Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

This is the code that gives the error:

```
public Java.Lang.Object [] GetSections ()
{ 
    var intPtr = JNIEnv.NewArray (sections.ToArray ());
    var array = new JavaArray<Java.Lang.Object> (intPtr, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
    return (Java.Lang.Object []) array;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're casting `JavaArray<Java.Lang.Object>` to `Java.Lang.Object []`.

Change the return type of `GetSessions()` to `JavaArray<Java.Lang.Object>`

```
public JavaArray<Java.Lang.Object> GetSections ()
{ 
    var intPtr = JNIEnv.NewArray (sections.ToArray ());
    return new JavaArray<Java.Lang.Object> (intPtr, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
}
```

Comment: Now the error changed to this:

Error CS0738: `EmployeeDirectory.Android.PeopleGroupsAdapter' does not implement interface member `Android.Widget.ISectionIndexer.GetSections()' and the best implementing candidate `EmployeeDirectory.Android.PeopleGroupsAdapter.GetSections()' return type `Android.Runtime.JavaArray<Java.Lang.Object>' does not match interface member return type `Java.Lang.Object[]'

Comment: Change the return type of GetSections() on your interface also. The class must match the interface...

Comment: In what kind of file can I find GetSections() on the interface? It is a tutorial code so I don't know all of the code yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your second problem probably means that you have implemented a interfacit wich GetSections method needs a return type of Java.Lang.Object.

If you made your interface yourself you probably made the same mistake there as what you did in this method.

So:

```
public JavaArray<Java.Lang.Object> GetSections ()
{ 
    var intPtr = JNIEnv.NewArray (sections.ToArray ());
    return new JavaArray<Java.Lang.Object> (intPtr, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
}
```

and your interface should look like this:

```
public JavaArray<Java.Lang.Object> GetSections ();
```

i think you made the same mistake twice

Comment: Where should I edit the interface code? I can't find it anywhere. Isn't there a way to make the return type: 'return (Java.Lang.Object [])array;'?

Comment: Yes that's possible but it's not what you want.. You can return a array of objects but you want to return just one object. Maybe you could try to use the @Override annotation and change the return type of the method but i'm not sure if that works.. Or else a very ugly solution is to return a array every time with just one object in it (not recommended) but try the override first and let me know if it doesn't work